# Proof of $\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\le \:\:2-\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, summation

Proof of $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\le \:\:2-\frac{1}{n}$

The following proof is from a book, however, there is something that I don't quite understand

for $k\geq  2$ we have:

**(1)**: $\displaystyle\frac{1}{k^2}\le \frac{1}{k\left(k-1\right)}$

so

**(2)**:$\displaystyle \sum _{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\le \sum _{k=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{k\left(k-1\right)}\right)$

**(3)**:$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\le \:1+\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$

**(4)**:$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\le \:\:2-\frac{1}{n}$

I don't understand why in line **(2)**, on the right, we start the sum at $k=2$ while
on the left, we start on $k=1$. Why start at $k=2$?

Comment: What happens if we start that sum at $k=1$?

Comment: This step $\sum _{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\le \sum _{k=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{k\left(k-1\right)}\right)$ is uncorrect.

Comment: @user thanks. this has been driving me crazy

Comment: @NODE234 There is a typo in the book! You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed we have

$$\begin{aligned}\sum _{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)&=1+\sum _{k=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right) \\
&\le 1+\sum _{k=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{k\left(k-1\right)}\right) \\
&=1+\sum _{k=2}^n\left(\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k\right) \\
&=2-\frac1n\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 2):

You are right, that the inequality (2) is wrong. The correct inequality should be :

$\displaystyle \sum _{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right) = \displaystyle \sum _{k=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right) + 1 \le \sum _{k=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{k\left(k-1\right)}\right) + \mathbf{1}$

which is also consistent with (3), (4).

The summation has to start from $k=2$ on the right-hand side because otherwise you would get division by zero  $\frac{1}{1\cdot(1-1)} = \frac{1}{0}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $k(k-1)<k^2$ for $k>0$ but when $k=1$, $\dfrac{1}{n(n-1)}$ is not defined.

$\begin{aligned}\displaystyle \sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} &<\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k(k-1)} \\
 &= \sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k} \\
&=1-\frac{1}{n} \\ &\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} 
=1+\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} \\
&<1+1-\frac{1}{n} \\
&=2-\frac{1}{n} \end{aligned}$